# Create and execute an Oracle Stored Procedure for a select query in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, select, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer with Oracle 11g.

I face a strange issue creating a simple stored procedure for a Select query that doesn't need any input parameters as such. It just selects from a user defined function from the "dual" table.

These are the issues I face:

1. I am not able to create a procedure with no input parameters (because I don't need to use any parameter value in the select!). But the syntax does not allow me to have zero parameters, it demands a `REF_CURSOR` out parameter. Is the `REF_CURSOR` a compulsory thing in SQL Developer procedures? Is it anything to do with procedures involving a Select query?
2. The select query demands an `INTO` clause (a variable to copy the query result) in SQL developer. Is it mandatory?
3. Even if I used an `INTO` clause, I can't figure out the syntax to declare a temporary variable to copy the query result into this variable. So that I can use this *out* variable in my program snippet.

This is my procedure block:

```
Create or Replace PROCEDURE Getmarketdetails
AS
DECLARE temp varchar;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  INTO temp from  dual;
END Getmarketdetails;
```

I get these errors on compiling the procedure:

1. *PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of
   the    following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type
       
   current cursor     delete    exists prior external language The
   symbol "begin" was       substituted for "DECLARE" to continue.*
2. *PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with          << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge .*

All I need is the perfect script syntax to create the stored procedure for this and also execute it using the *exec* command. And some clarifications to questions raised above. Appreciate if someone can oblige ! :)

Comment: if it's a simple select why do you need a procedure? also you stire the result in a variable but don't do anything with it, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I need to run this in an Nhibernate C# code. My actual query involves selecting from a Function from dual. Something like "Select <function()> from dual" !! This was proving hard in a direct approach in Nhibernate, hence the Stored proc approach!

Comment: Regarding the unused variable, it is just to check the syntax. I just need the basic syntax!! Hence used a simple query for clarifications!

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is incorrect - you need to declare a length for your varchar and you don't need the declare.

```
Create or Replace PROCEDURE Getmarketdetails
AS
temp varchar(100);
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  INTO temp from  dual;
END Getmarketdetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create or Replace PROCEDURE Getmarketdetails 
AS 
  temp varchar2(20);
BEGIN 
  SELECT 'stack overflow' INTO temp from dual;
  Dbms_output.put_line(temp);
END Getmarketdetails;
```

Some modification done in your procedure. Don't write declare and mention variables as per your need.